# Using update() method for two duplicate sets

Tags: python, set

I want to add two duplicate sets together. Why does my code return None?

```
firstset = {1, 2, 3}
secondset = {1, 2, 3}
thirdset = firstset.update(secondset)
print(thirdset)
```

Comment: Because [`set.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) returns `None`. It updates the `set` in place.

Comment: Wait, why are you updating sets with duplicates when set can only contain unique elements?

Comment: I realize that. I wanted to see how update() method behaves on two duplicate sets because I knew the update() method will exclude any duplicate item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because you're assigning the return value of `.update()` to `thirdset`. The updates occur in-place (i.e. they mutate `firstset`), and the function returns `None`.

The code snippet below shows what you were probably intending. Note that `firstset` and `thirdset` point to the same location in memory, so updates using `firstset` will be reflected when attempted to read the contents of `thirdset`, and vice versa.

```py
firstset = {1, 2, 3}
secondset = {1, 2, 3}
firstset.update(secondset)
thirdset = firstset
print(thirdset)
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Set update would update the set it was invoked on and returns None.

Answer (score 0):

That is because python set.update() method return None.
Read documentation for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

if you want to get the addition, what you can do is,

```
firstset.update(secondset)
print(firstset)
```

because from the update function, the firstset is the set that is updated with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python's built-in container classes mostly use [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), so that methods that mutate a `set` return `None`.  (An exception to this rule is `pop()`, which both removes and returns a set element.)

So instead of

```py
thirdset = firstset.update(secondset)
```

you can write:

```py
firstset.update(secondset)
thirdset = firstset
```

Or if you want to leave `firstset` alone, use the set union operator `|`:

```py
thirdset = firstset | secondset
```

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark: You're thinking of `dict`.  `set` has already had the `|` operator for several versions.

Answer (score 0):

It updates the firstset. You can use | as well

```
firstset = {1, 2, 3}
secondset = {5, 2, 4}
firstset |= secondset
print(firstset)
```